# How to test pivot_root?

Tags: c, linux

I want to test the `pivot_root` command line, which moves the root file system of the current process to the directory put_old and makes new_root the new root file system. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pivot_root.8.html

But I always get

```
pivot_root: failed to change root from `.' to `old-root/': Invalid argument
```

I use fedora as base root, I have a Archlinux in my home folder

```
[root@localhost arch-root]# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  mnt  old-root  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var

[root@localhost arch-root]# pivot_root . old-root/ 
pivot_root: failed to change root from `.' to `old-root/': Invalid argument
```

I also try to call linux function `pivot_root("/chroot_test", "/chroot_test/old-root");`
Got same error.

Any idea about this ?

**Update 1:**

I also try to test `pivot_root` in Docker.

I mount this arch-root in to Docker container.

But get the following error: `Operation not permitted`

```
root@00d871ce892b:/# cd test_root/
root@00d871ce892b:/test_root# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  mnt  old-root  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv     sys  test_pivot_root  test_pivot_root.c   tmp  usr  var
root@00d871ce892b:/test_root# pivot_root . tmp/
pivot_root: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 2):

`pivot_root` is subject to a number of important limitations; one of them is that the new root must be on a different filesystem from the current one. In your case, unless you have a filesystem mounted at `/home`, chances are that your Arch system is installed on the same filesystem as the current root.

Chances are that you don't want `pivot_root()` anyway, though. It's primarily intended to be used during system startup, and will have some *really strange* effects when used on a running system. You probably want to use `chroot` instead, as that doesn't affect the rest of the system, and isn't subject to any of the odd limitations of `pivot_root`. Try, for instance:

```
chroot arch-root /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Here is some other information. 1, I have tried chroot firstly. It works. So I move to pivot_root. 2 You are correct, my arch-root is in my current file system. But I also try like this : i mount from virtual box share folder to fedora. it still does not work

Comment: Why would you want to move to `pivot_root`? `pivot_root` and `chroot` do almost completely different things.

Comment: Hello man, because I am a geek!. Just kidding. Because I am doing some research about linux container. they seem change chroot to pivot_root. Btw chroot can be jailbreak.

Comment: `pivot_root` is not used with containers. As I mentioned in my answer, it's really only useful during system startup.

Comment: Docker lxc have change the chroot to the pivot_root as default method long time ago....please never be so sure about something

Comment: They're using `pivot_root()` in conjunction with filesystem namespaces, though. Totally different from using it on your real root filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by the author of the question:

> I have found **the solution:**
>
> Run docker with --privileged=true
>
> So we can test pivot_root in the docker container